# Different session timeouts for admin and users in CAKEPHP 2.0. is it possible?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.0 for developing a website. Site will contain only 2 types of users. Admin and users(customers). now I need to set session time out 10 minutes for customer and 1 hour for admin. is it possible ?. My core.php file contains the line like this,

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults'      => 'php',
    'cookie'        => 'xyz',
    'timeout'       => 10,
    'checkAgent'    => false,
));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is more correct you do this condition in the `AppController` than to change your core.php this magnitude. You can make only this:

```
Configure::write('Session.timeout', 60);
```

And if you're using Acl, verify if user is admin using his own Acl method instead `strripos`.

Comment: Yes i tried this way first. but i cant able to override the session time out from app controller

Comment: @Cakephp.Saint Check [this code](http://pastebin.com/UngCkQCj) and try use on your `beforeFilter()` method in AppController. You will see that the value has been changed.

Comment: Yes i used in the same in beforeFilter only.. Its not working :(

Comment: The output values ​​of the code pastebin not alter? Very strange, I tested the same code in both versions of Cakephp and worked correctly.

Comment: Yes it working now.. Cleared cache/cookies and tried .. Fine now

Answer (score 3):

I added the following lines in core.php file. For quick fix

> if(strripos($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'],"admin/"))
>   { 
>        Configure::write('Session', array(
>              'defaults'        => 'php',
>              'cookie'      => 'xyz',
>              'timeout'     => 60,
>              'checkAgent'  => false,
>       )); 
>   }
>   else
>   {
>          Configure::write('Session', array(
>                  'defaults'      => 'php',
>                   'cookie'        => 'xyz',
>                   'timeout'       => 10,
>                'checkAgent'    => false,
>               ));
>   }