# Cakephp session timeout based on logged in user

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-2.6, cakephp-2.x

I have different groups of users, and for some group I need to give different session timeout. There is a question here, but it is not working

[Different session timeouts for admin and users in CAKEPHP 2.0. is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476929/different-session-timeouts-for-admin-and-users-in-cakephp-2-0-is-it-possible)

When putting this `Configure::write('Session.timeout', 1);` in AppController's `beforeFilter` before checking if user is logged in, namely before `if ($this->Auth->user('id')) {` line, it works fine, and user is being logged out after 1 minute of inactivity, however when I put that line after `if` condition, which I need in order to check the group of the user - it does not work.

cake version 2.6

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have session destroyed after user is being logged in and you change session settings, something like that:

```
if ($this->Auth->user('id')) {
   Configure::write('Session.timeout', 3);
   $this->Session->destroy();
   $this->Session->write('userData', 'user data again');
}
```

Comment: What says Configure::read('Session.timeout') after $this->Session->destroy() ?

Comment: it outputs 1, but even without all session destroy and write things, if I would put `Configure::write('Session.timeout', 1);` and then after that check `Configure::read('Session.timeout')` it was always 1, but cake is ignoring it. thanks

Comment: `Configure::write('Session', array(
  'defaults' => 'php',
  'cookie' => 'SESSIONID',
  'ini' => array(
   'session.cookie_secure' => true,
   'session.cookie_httponly' => true
  )
 ));

` site is always being served through https, redirect is done both from apache vhosts file and also JIC from htaccess

Comment: Just to make sure, you're running this: ` if ($this->Auth->user('id')) {
   Configure::write('Session.timeout', 3);
   $this->Session->destroy();
   $this->Session->write('userData', 'user data again');
   debug(Configure::read('Session.timeout'));
}` and it shows "1"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92642/discussion-between-raph-and-dav).